# Database connection failing

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database connection file in my web application and for some reason the server is trying to connect to the location of: `***.**.**.215` for the ip address rather than: `***.**.**.222` which is what is typed in the file. The code is below:

```
<?php 

   // Configure the following items to match your database! 

     // Database Location 
     $location = '***.**.**.222'; 

     // Database Name 
     $name = '';

     // Database Username 
     $username = ''; 

     // Database Password 
     $Password = ''; 

  // Do not alter anything beyond this line! 

     // Create connection
     $con=mysqli_connect($location,$username,$password,$name);

     // Check connection
     if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
     {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
     }

?>
```

Google Chrome shows this exact error message: I removed the credentials from it.

```
Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'username'@'***.**.**.215' (using password: NO) in /home/www/hiddenforsecurity/shop/config/connect.php on line 20
Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'username'@'***.**.**.215' (using password: NO)
```

I'm not sure what in the world to do or what is wrong, when I replace `$location` in the `$con` with the actual ip address, it works perfect. It's just when I use the variable `$location` that it doesn't work.

**I removed important private credentials from this question. Sorry hackers.**

Comment: Sounds like you're editing the wrong file? Try erasing everything in this file and run it again. Just do it, to be sure.

Comment: No i'm editing the right file. It is a application I've built from the ground up with no frameworks. I know it is the right one.

Comment: `using password: NO` – that makes me strongly suspect that this is not really your code, or it is not the point in the script where that error message originates from.

Comment: Just try it, for science.

Comment: You may have to switch from `$location = '***.**.**.222';` to `$location = 'localhost';` - give that a try.

Comment: I've typed every last little bit of this code from the ground up. The database is using a password. It is trying to connect to .215 rather than .222 in the IP address that is why it is showing this way. @WesleyMurch, I tried removing everything and running the page again, the errors went away and appeared only a blank page. Just like I figured.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I am not using a localhost the ip address for the database is `***.**.**.222`

Comment: @MitchEvans, thanks - that helps narrow it down. Are you running this file directly or is it `include`d somewhere else? Try running it directly, just so *we* know for sure this is all the code.

Comment: Right now I am running it directly for testing purposes. But it will be included in other parts of the application.

Comment: It still doesn't make sense... it's only when you use a variable to store the IP value?

Comment: I run quite a few sites and most of them require an IP address, however there are 2 of those which require `localhost` to be the DB address to use. Did you at least try it?

Comment: When I do: `$con=mysqli_connect('***.**.**.222',$username,$password,$name);` the connection works. But when I do: `$con=mysqli_connect($location,$username,$password,$name);` I get the error message in the question.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, Just did, still couldn't connect.

Comment: Voted to close because Typo related questions aren't applicable to anybody else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Database Password 
     $Password = ''; 
// Create connection
     $con=mysqli_connect($location,$username,$password,$name);
```

Change the capital $Password to $password.

Answer (score 0):

You're on an client with ip address *.215 and you're trying to connect to MySQL server with ip address *.222, so make sure that the user '$username' on the MySQL server is allowed to connect from the ip *.215 you're using. (by default every user is allowed to connect only from local 127.0.0.1).

The connection you're trying to establish doesn't use password, notice that the variable you're using in the mysqli_connect(...) function is written *$password* and in the configuration above *$Password* (first letter upper case).

I suggest you to check the error log file (if you're using apache it is error.log inside the httpd folder), because in that file are logged all warning and errors and can help you solve problems, in this case probably there is something like this:

> Variable **$password** undefined in **page.php** on line **nnn**.